Recaptcha Enterprise Serverside validation error
As per documentation, JSON payload should be like
{
  "event": {
    "token": "TOKEN",
    "expectedAction": "USER_ACTION",
    "siteKey": "site_key",
  }
}

Trying to build data something like this,
Dim data  = New Dictionary(Of String, String) From{
                            {"token", token},
                            {"expectedAction", "Action"},
                            {"siteKey", "site_key"}}

Error is,

Status:Bad Request

{
  "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "Invalid JSON payload received. Unexpected token.\ntoken=03AFcWeA4YlT5x\n^",
    "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
  }
}


Make sure you enable the reCAPTCHA Enterprise API from the gcloud console.
The error you are getting is “INVALID_ARGUMENT” when the arguments passed to a command is invalid. After creating a dictionary you need to serialize by using JsonConvert it to JSON format by using below command. For more details on how to serialize JSON refer to this also.
Dim json As String = JsonConvert.SerializeObeject(data)

It is a Server side validation error. Check the key value pair that matches what API expects like "token": "TOKEN","expectedAction": "USER_ACTION","siteKey": "site_key" properly.
To check the generated JSON is valid by using the below command Console.WriteLine(json) it will print the Json string.

As per this documentation, I dont need to run any command in gcloud CLI ( though a ran it) https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/gcloud#on-gcp. Still same error

What does the error code, message and the status mean that there is some misconfiguration in the json payload itself. Since it is not a valid json payload, So still getting the same error it seems.
